# Javascript/AJAX POST multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I am using an app which tracks search requests. I do not havy any insights how this is done, but I used live http headers to throw everything away which is not used for the search request itself or for the tracking. The form uses POST requests to submit data to the server

The app alows me to create some permanent urls for search requests. But if I am using these there is no tracking of the search request.

My idea ist to use some JavaScript Code to check whether it is one of my permanent urls and then sending a POST request in the background so the app would count the request.

Live http headers got me something like this:

```
>...
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------568349381375
...


>-----------------------------568349381375\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENT"\r\n
\r\n
hld$comp_AAAACH$c$comp_AAA...sf$search\r\n
-----------------------------568349381375\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEW"\r\n
\r\n
/wEPDwUBMA9kFgICAQ9kFgI...icMj66rRouZ7xxOgQ==\r\n
-----------------------------568349381375\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hld$comp_AAA...$value0$tbValue"\r\n
\r\n
my_search_word\r\n
```

Now when I repeat this request with live http headers it gets counted. So how could I pack this into a POST request by using AJAX? I tested simple request but struggle with "multipart/form-data" which seems to be used for file transfers.

Comment: You should post some code, so I can understand what you are doing. You can learn about ajax requests using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript

Just hat to add "--" to the boundary part in the header.